# Jquery async setup

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous

I have a php script which when fired, collects some data on different sites using an AJAX call in jquery, and displays the results in a Div.

I also have a lightbox plugin which needs to be reinitialised after the result of the ajax call has loaded. To enable this, I've turned async off ($.ajaxSetup({async:false});) so it doesnt load before the results div has finished loading.

This works fine, except for in Chrome (and I would assume IE) where the 'loading' image is not displayed when this setting is in use.

Is there a smart way around this?

Comment: Why do you **need** async off? If you need some processing once a request from the server is made, use a callback but keep async on.

Comment: Why don't you do it asynchronously and then reinitialize OR initialize for the first time your lightbox in the success callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still do it asynchronously, just do your initialisation inside the success callback function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'',
    data:'',
    success:function(response){
        // init your lightbox here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'm so new to jquery but I'm slowly starting to hate it less each day!

Comment: @thatguy Not long until you get to the point where you absolutely love it and don't want to do anything without it anymore :)